# Larastan and the return type

Tags: laravel

I would like, for my new LARAVEL project, to have a super clean code and use [LARASTAN](https://github.com/nunomaduro/larastan) which will inspect my code.

For now I will limit myself to level 5 (max is 9). Apparently this is the minimum acceptable.

With this level 5, I must have done something that surprises me and would like to have your opinion.

In a controller I have this:

```
public function index(): AnonymousResourceCollection
{
    $organizations = $this->organizationRepository->index();

    return OrganizationResource::collection($organizations);
}
```

And so that LARASTAN does not raise an error, I had to put a this return type : **AnonymousResourceCollection**.

It disturbs me as it is not usual....

Your opinions ? Am I good ? Or should I change ?

Answer (score 1):

Very good practice. That's how it should be. I agree with your opinion.